# writing contents of an array into a c++ vector from an offset

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write contents of an array into a vector starting from an offset.

```
std::copy(arr,&arr[100],std::back_inserter(vect[offset]);
```

here arr is the array of 100 integers. and vect is a vector containing integres. What is wrong with the above piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `insert()` function, specifically the variant that takes an offset and range:

```
vect.insert(vect.begin() + offset, arr,&arr[100]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument of [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) must support the `push_back()` operation, and `int` does not and an `int` is the result of `vect[offset]` (assuming `vect` is a `vector<int>`).

If you can use an iterator instead of an offset you can use [`std::vector::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

Answer (score 2):

`std::back_inserter` inserts at the back, not at an offset. What you want is `std::inserter`, which takes (and updates) an insert-position iterator.

You probably want `std::inserter(vect, vect.begin() + offset)`.

Note that this will repeatedly relocate the tail sequence on every insert operation. As @Nim suggests, the straight-up `insert()` operation is preferable in this case, since it inserts the entire range in one step.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is that [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) looks like an iterator, but it calls `push_back` on its argument, which must be a container supporting `push_back()`, not an element of a container.

If you want to insert from an offset, you have to find the iterator corresponding to that position, and pass that as 3rd argument to `std::copy`, or use the right overload of [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). Of course, you have to make sure the container is large enough, i.e that the range from `offset_iterator` to the end is at least size `100`.